# Eigenfunctions heuristics for self-conjugate priors

Tags: statistics, reference-request, bayesian

**Also asked on** [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389085/eigenfunctions-heuristics-for-self-conjugate-priors).

I am looking for a citable reference (books, research papers, PhD theses, *not* websites, internal reports, etc.) about the heuristic interpretation of self-conjugate priors as "eigenfunctions for the conditioning operator".
This is best explained (though without reference) in the Wikipedia page [Conjugate prior#Interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Analogy_with_eigenfunctions[citation_needed]).

In a nutshell: A *statistical model* is any family $\{P_\theta\}_\theta$ of probability distributions, parametrized by $\theta\in T$ (e.g., $T\subset \mathbb R$ or $T\subset \mathbb R^k$).
Some data $X:=(X_1,\dotsc, X_k)$ is sampled from the model in two stages:

- firstly, we let $\Theta\in T$ be a $Q$-distributed random variable;
- secondly, we draw $X_1,\dotsc, X_k$ in such a way that $X_1,\dotsc, X_k\mid \Theta\sim P_\Theta$ conditionally i.i.d..

The *posterior distribution of $Q$ given $X$* is then defined as $Q^X:=Q[\Theta\in \cdot\mid X]$.

A family of distributions $\{Q_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ (again $A\subset \mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^k$) is *self-conjugate* (for a fixed model) if the posterior distribution $Q_\alpha^X$ satisfies $Q_\alpha^X=Q_{\alpha'}$ for some $\alpha'\in A$.

Heuristically, $Q_\alpha$ is (sort of) an "eigenfunction" for the conditioning operator $\mathbf E[\cdot \mid X]$.

Comment: You have asked in a flag to cross-post this to CrossValidated (and not migrated). I think you are under the impression that this is something that the mods (or the community) does for you --- but in fact, all you need to do is go to CrossValidated and ask your question. If you decide to do this, **be sure to include links to each post**, so that if one gets answered then no one will waste their time duplicating the effort. Good luck

Comment: @davidlowryduda thank you for your kind the clarification. I was in fact under the impression that cross-posting is a kind of duplication, thus requiring moderators' approval. (I will read the guidelines more carefully...)